# Get element by placeholder. Code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code in the JsFiddler below works when I get the element by ID, but when I try to get it by placeholder (because there is no ID in the input I'm trying to interact with) The code won't work. My tries are below:

```
var el = $("[placeholder='Select Country']");
var el = $("input:placeholder(Select Country)");
var el = $("input").attr("placeholder","Select Country");
var el = document.querySelectorAll('[placeholder="Select Country"]');
```

```js
function setKeywordText(text) {
    var el = document.getElementById("gwt-debug-keywords-text-area");
    el.value = text;
    var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
    evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
    el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

setKeywordText("test");
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder = "Select Country" id ="gwt-debug-keywords-text-area" />
```

Thank you,

Comment: Use this `document.querySelector('[placeholder="Select Country"]')`

Comment: In your examples, you get a JQuery object back, not a HMTLElement. To get an element from a JQuery object, add: [0]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var el = $('*[placeholder="Select Country"]');
```

You may have to reference the input as:

```
el[0]
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Can you explain what the * means and why it doesn't work without it?

Comment: @CreekBarbara It's probably redundant.  It worked for me without it.  It's a wildcard selector that selects all elements with that placeholder.  Since placeholder isn't a unique selector it returns an array of DOM elements instead of a singular element.  At least that's how I understand it.